# kettle mongo _id

Tags: mongodb, upsert, kettle

I'm trying to upsert by using the _id field in Mongo.

I've tried to recover first the _id by using a Json Input step, no luck with $._id or $._id.$oid

Anyone knows how to upsert by _id?

Comment: By 'kettle', are you referring to Pentaho Kettle?  If so, what are you trying to achieve?  The input step in Kettle is normally a query to find data, not update/upsert.

Comment: Yes, Pentaho Kettle Data Integration. I'm trying to select first a document, recover its data by using Json Input (including _id), do some changes and upsert the document by using the _id previously recovered.

Comment: @Stennie is correct about the input step. Unfortunately, I know nothing about Mongo. If you're looking for how you would typically do upserts with surrogate key management in Kettle, look at the Insert/Update step, and the Combination lookup/update step.

Comment: Ok, let me explain the question. 1) Recover a document from mongo using mongo input step 2) extract the fields using Json Input step, including the _id 3) Upsert the document by _id using mongo output step.

I have thousands of transformations like this, but no one using the _id to do an upsert. The problem here (i guess) is the ObjectId type. When i recover the _id i only can set the String type, but the mongo output step doesn't like this stringified _id.

Any idea about how to recover the _id and using it to upsert in mongo/kettle?

Comment: @user1688569: this data transformation really sounds like a problem much better suited to using one of the many [supported drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for MongoDB.  You could perhaps try using the formats in [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) where ObjectID would be `{"$oid": "<id>"}`. It would also be helpful to paste the "Preview JSON" generated in the [MongoDB output step](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDb+output).  Oddly none of the Kettle doc examples seem to include an `_id` field.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the _id, transform it into the extended JSON notation indicated by Stennie with a `Modified Javascript Value` script like:

```
var _id = '{ "$oid": "' + _id + '" }';
```

In your `MongoDB Output` step, set the `JSON` column to `Y`for the `_id` row. I'm not sure when this JSON option was introduced but found it in the latest [CI build of Kettle](http://ci.pentaho.com/view/Data%20Integration/job/Kettle/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Kettle/assembly/dist/pdi-ce-TRUNK-SNAPSHOT.zip) today.